# Encontrar o elemento com o maior número

Tags: java, arraylist

Eu estou fazendo um sistema de eleição básico, mas estou com um problema em dizer qual candidato foi eleito. No caso, eu adicionei três candidatos (x, y, z) numa `ArrayList`, coloquei dois votos no x, três no y e quatro no z. Quando quero saber qual foi o que ganhou (no caso o que obteve mais votos) ele imprime todos os 3 candidatos.

```
public void eleitoPresidente() {
    int maior = 0;
    for (Candidato e: candidato) {
        if(e.votos > maior) {
            maior = e.votos;
            System.out.println("O presidente eleito é: " + e.nome);
        }
    }
}
```

Quero que ele imprima somente o candidato com o maior número de votos.

Comment: retira o println do for e exibe o Candidato fora dele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mantendo o algoritmo que fez inicialmente tem dois problemas, não está guardando qual é o maior em lugar algum. E está dizendo quem foi eleito toda vez que um novo candidato avaliado tem mais votos que o anterior. Então o correto seria:

```
import java.util.*;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Candidato> candidato = new ArrayList<>();
        candidato.add(new Candidato("joao", 4));
        candidato.add(new Candidato("jose", 2));
        candidato.add(new Candidato("joaquim", 7));
        int maiorVotos = 0;
        Candidato maiorCandidato = null;
        for (Candidato e: candidato) {
            if(e.votos > maiorVotos) {
                maiorVotos = e.votos;
                maiorCandidato = e;
            }
        }
        if (maiorCandidato != null) {
            System.out.println("O presidente eleito é: " + maiorCandidato.nome);
        }
    }
}

class Candidato {
    public String nome;
    public int votos;
    public Candidato (String nome, int votos) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.votos = votos;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/EqWzs1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nthzmlav-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/CandidateElect.java).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método [`Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) para ordenar os candidatos por algum critério (no caso o número de votos **em ordem decrescente**), e então pegar o primeiro deles:

```
public void eleitoPresidente() {
    List<Candidato> copia = new ArrayList<>(candidato);
    Collections.sort(copia, (a, b) -> b.votos - a.votos);
    System.out.println("O presidente eleito é: " + copia.get(0).nome);
}
```

Comment: EU pensei em fazer assim, mas desisti porque já me ferrei por ter dado uma solução mais simples :)

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma ira funcionar

```
public void eleitoPresidente() {
    Candidato maiorCand = null;
    int maior = 0;
    for (Candidato e : candidato) {
        if (e.votos > maior) {
            maiorCand = e;
        }
    }
    if (maiorCand != null) {
        System.out.println("O presidente eleito é: " + maiorCand.nome);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Não teve presidente eleito");
    }
}
```

Comment: Vai dar um erro de compilação porque `maiorCand` pode não ter sido inicializado na linha do `System.out`. Para resolver isso, é só atribuir `null` na declaração de `maiorCand` e deixar dar `NullPointerException` se não houver candidatos.

Comment: Problema corrigido